Curve bend, to center
You want to create a scene of a flower blooming.
However, the way the petals bend seems a little strange.
They bend normally when standing upright, with no noise on the stem,
but when I add noise to the stem, the petals are facing the wrong way.
How do I fix it...?


my blend file are here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mf9YdH1wAMRwY8ukca2K3XA5E1ynHZMD/view?usp=sharing

It's a matter of instancing the petals around the flower before applying the tangent of the stem to the flower. That way, the petals inherit the orientation. I have added a second geometry nodes set-up to show the difference in the below blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W3gEt-Sze11HKGvzo4yr114vDMJj15d8/view?usp=sharing


Using Beziers also seems like a great idea. Thank you for the response!
